# Programmatically loading native libraries in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Our Xamarin app supports some device-specific hardware features for a specific Android device packing an RFID scanner. We don't like to clutter up our basic app with stuff related to this device, so we created a separate Xamarin library containing the logic for this device, which is built to be an Asset of the Droid project. During statup of the app, we check if we are on this specific device and if we are, we programmatically load the hardware specific Xamarin library using `Assembly.Load(...)` and activate it.

The problem we run into is that the manufacturer of the device provided us with some native android libraries (.so files) that must be used. Normally you would include those in the Droid project with build action `AndroidNativeLibrary`, but since we want to encapsulate all stuff related to this device in a separate project, we don't want to do this. We have tried the following:

1. To add them to the device specific Xamarin library with build action `AndroidNativeLibrary`, but then the app cannot find them. They are probably not saved to disk and therefore they cannot be found.
2. To add them to the device specific Xamarin library with build action `Embedded Resource` and save them to disk when the library is started, but none of the locations, where the app searches for native libraries it needs, is accessible. Therefore the app cannot find them and the library cannot work.

I am starting to think that Android has shielded this kind of behavior off, but I am still hoping for some of you to help me with a good trick. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is this relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47577462/how-to-call-methods-of-a-so-file-from-xamarin-android

Comment: @FreakyAli no that is the regular way to go when including the .so files in your Xamarin.Droid project.